# How to make FlashDevelop show line error and where it happened with Haxe?

Tags: try-catch, haxe, openfl, hxcpp

I've been using Haxe for a while and I'm debuging with the Windows target (OpenFL).

When I put a `try`/`catch` somewhere it just says for example `"Null object reference"` - it doesn't say the line number and the class, so I have to keep putting traces to find in which line it has thrown the error.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to enable stack traces by adding the following define to your `project.xml` file if you're compiling in release mode:

```
<haxedef name="HXCPP_STACK_LINE" />
```

Also, you won't be able to catch null reference exceptions or get stack traces for them unless the following is defined (for performance reasons):

```
<haxedef name="HXCPP_CHECK_POINTER" />
```

With these two, you should see a stack trace in FlashDevelop's Output panel.

You can find some good info on these flags and hxcpp debugging in general [here](http://gamehaxe.com/2012/09/14/hxcpp-built-in-debugging/). You might also want to check out the [crashdumper](https://github.com/larsiusprime/crashdumper) library.

Comment: i'm using catch (e:Dynamic){
   trace(e);
  } and still i only get "MainDomain.hx:218: Null Object Reference" being mainDomain.hx:218 the line of the catch... am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You can just leave the exception uncaught if you want to see the stack trace. Alternatively, you can use `haxe.CallStack` to get at the stack trace: https://gist.github.com/Gama11/adcc268fb00d3f442c969e54940db831